# trying to parse the log file and redirecting output to saperate file

Tags: perl

Hello am trying to parse log file and redirecting the output to some number of files but lastly some junk named file is creating..
    GLOB(0x152c4e4).txt, GLOB(0x1545c1c).txt like that
In code am defining each variable in global

```
my $g1logFIle = " " ;
my $V1gFIle = " " ;
my $D1logFIle = " " ;
my $D1logFIle = " " ;
```

Again am opening a file to redirect its output-

```
open( $g1logFIle, ">>" , g1logFIle.".txt" ) or die $!;
open( $V1logFIle, ">>" , V1logFIle.".txt" ) or die $!;
open( $D1logFIle, ">>" , D1logFIle.".txt" ) or die $!;
```

And while parsing am just printing my parsed output in file-

```
print $D1logFIle "+D1Launch Request ", ($D1hMetrics{NoOfTimes} + 1), "\n\n"
print $V1logFIle  "+VOD Launch Request ", ($V1Metrics{NoOfTimes} + 1), "\n\n";
```

where am doing wrong??

Comment: You asked this yesterday and got several answers...

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, I get files like `g1logFIle.txt`. The `GLOB(0x152c4e4).txt` files would have been created if you used the `$g1logFIle` variable in the file name. You should use different variables for the file handle (the first argument of `open`) and the file name (the third argument).

```
open my $G_HANDLE, '>>', "$g1logFIle.txt" or die $!;
```